# How to remove custom white space from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, whitespace

I have a below string in python

`"982 123717335177    "`

As you can see that it has a white space after `982` and some white space at the end. I wanted to remove the white space at the end so I did

```
my_str = "982 123717335177    "
my_str = my_str.replace(" ", "")
print(my_str)

output = "982123717335177"
```

I didn't realized that doing above will also remove the white space after `982` which I don't want.

Expected output is `"982 123717335177"`. Can anyone please suggest some good ideas. Thanks

Comment: `my_str.rstrip()`

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica  `my_str.rstrip()` worked fine. Thanks